# My bound combobox is not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am new to MVVM and xaml.  I have created a combobox for a list of PhoneTypes but since i have set the binding to the PhoneTypes loaded from the database is not longer showing on the view (in runtime).

Data

```
string SQLPhoneTypes = "select phone_type_id, description from phone_types";

//get the phone types for lookups

MySqlCommand cmdGetTypes = new MySqlCommand(SQLPhoneTypes, ConnectData.connection);
MySqlDataReader drDataTypes = cmdGetTypes.ExecuteReader();
_contact.PhoneTypes = new List<ContactModel.PhoneType>();

while (drDataTypes.Read())
{
    _contact.PhoneTypes.Add(new ContactModel.PhoneType()
    {
        PhoneTypeID = drDataTypes.GetInt16("phone_type_id"),
        Description = drDataTypes.GetString("description")
    });
}
```

Model

```
public List<PhoneType > PhoneTypes
{
    get { return _phonetypes; }
    set { _phonetypes = value; OnPropertyChanged("PhoneTypes"); }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<PhoneTypesLoaded> PhoneTypes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PhoneTypesLoaded>();

public class PhoneTypesLoaded
{
    public int phoneTypeID { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

if (PhoneTypes.Count == 0)
{
    ContactData.LoadPhoneTypes (c);
    for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < c.PhoneTypes.Count; iCounter++)
    {
        PhoneTypes.Add(new PhoneTypesLoaded { phoneTypeID = c.PhoneTypes[iCounter].PhoneTypeID, description = c.PhoneTypes[iCounter].Description });
    }
}
```

View

```
    <GroupBox x:Name="grpPhone" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Width="200" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="pnScrollPhone" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel x:Name="pnPhone" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Phones}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PhoneTypes}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="cboPhoneType" ItemsSource="{Binding description}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Text="{Binding phoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </GroupBox>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved via chat - the answer was to include a List<> of PhoneTypes in the Phone class, which could then be bound to the ComboBox.

Also, the inner ItemsControl was not needed, and was removed

Comment: Is it only the combobox that is not displaying, or is the txtPhone TextBox not showing either?

Comment: I have just altered it again as you suggested, I did not spot that you have removed the ItemsControl and Data template above it.  It now looks like this

Comment: <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ComboBox x:Name="cboPhoneType" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PhoneTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="description" />
                                        <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Text="{Binding phoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"/>

Comment: I think DisplayMemberPath may be case sensitive - can you try "Description" with a capital D?

Comment: Where is your list "Phones" ? What type of object is Phones a list of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135854/discussion-between-theresa-ferguson-and-s-mg).